# Undefined variable: blogcat (View: /home/techpriest/joseph/resources/views/admin/view_category.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

Undefined variable: blogcat (View: /home/techpriest/joseph/resources/views/admin/view_category.blade.php) this is my error message in laravel 8 but when I look at my code all seems well.
here is my code.

AdminController

```
public function addBlogCat (Request $request){
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();
            $blogcat = new Foliocategories;
            $blogcat->name = $data['category_name'];
            $blogcat->save();
            return redirect ('/blog/categories');
        }
        return view ('admin.view_category');
    }
    public function viewBlogCat (){
        $blogcat = DB::select('select * from foliocategories');
        return view ('admin.view_category', ['blogcat'=>$blogcat]);
    }
```

And here is my view;

```
    @foreach($blogcat as $blogcat)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $blogcat->id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $blogcat->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $blogcat->created_at }}</td>
                                        <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Due</span></td>
                                        <td class="action h4">
                                            <div class="table-action-buttons">
                                                <a class="edit button button-box button-xs button-info" href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></a>
                                                <a class="delete button button-box button-xs button-danger" href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
```

Comment: The code isn't passing an array of data in the  `addBlogCat()` method. If you compare `return view ('admin.view_category');` to `return view ('admin.view_category', ['blogcat'=>$blogcat]);`, you'll notice the difference.

Comment: Also: `@foreach($blogcat as $blogcat)` - you are overwriting your array with the loop variable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two issues here. In the `addBlogCat` action, you don't inject any blog category. The `viewBlogCat` is not bad, but in the view, you are using a loop with a model instance.

What about rewrite the code to this, lets use full meaningful variable names:

```php
public function addBlogCategory(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        Foliocategories::create(['name' => $request->input('category_name')]);

            return redirect ('/blog/categories');
    }

    return view ('admin.view_category', [
        'blogCatogories' => Foliocategories::all();
    ]);
}
    
public function viewBlogCategories()
{
    $blogCategories = Foliocategories::all();
    return view ('admin.view_category', compact('blogCategories'));
}
```

Then in the view:

```php
@foreach($blogCategories as $blogCategory)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $blogCategory->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $blogCategory->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $blogCategory->created_at }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```